# Is it possible to load only part of a class in c#?

Tags: c#, performance

When I write:

```
string myString = "text";
```

I load the `string` class with all of its methods in C#. Is it possible to load only part of `string` class in C#? For example I load the method `Compare` or `Copy` from the `string` class and I do not need them.

My question is due to my need for improving performance and I thought that it might help if it's possible.

My program creates lot of strings in very big loop and if I make the `string` class faster or lighter I'm sure my performance will improve.

Comment: "Is it possible to load only part of string class in c#?" no. "my need for improving performance and i thought that maybe it can help" also no. Use a profiler and find out where the *real* bottlenecks are in your code.

Comment: The method is defined by the class, not the instance; the instance only contains the instance data.

Comment: Number of methods defined on given type does not affect performance of creating instance of that class.I think the problem is in the loop, not in the strings.

Comment: Write your own compiler ;)

Comment: If you need help with performance tuning you need to show the code you are having problem with. As for improving performance by not loading some functions from a class that is not possible nor would it change the performance.

Comment: @TheUknown, how would that help exactly..?

Comment: @walther because the OP has demonstrated a lack of understanding how compilers/linkers work.

Comment: @TheUknown You mean runtime, not compiler.  He could (probably?) use the MS compiler and still do this if he had his own runtime.

Answer (score 5):

That's not how objects/classes work. Every time you instantiate an object instance you're only allocating space for the individual object state (in `System.String`'s case, that's simply just an internal `Char[]` array). Class member implementations (their CIL/instructions) are not loaded and duplicated in memory for each object instantiated.

In OOP, instance methods can be considered exactly like static functions except with a hidden first parameter: the `this` pointer, which is passed in.

So this:

```
class Foo {
    private String _bar;
    public Int32 Baz(String qux) {
        return String.Concat( _bar, qux ).Length;
    }
}

// Usage:

Foo foo = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine( foo.Baz("lulz") );
```

Is equivalent to:

```
class Foo {
    String bar; // only data members ("state"), no methods/properties
}

// free-function: not a class member
Int32 Baz(Foo this, String qux) {
    return String.Concat( this.bar, qux ).Length;
}

// Usage:
Foo foo = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine( Baz( foo, "lulz") );
```

(Obviously when you add things like the vtable for overloaded methods it's more complicated, but this illustrates the basic idea)

To be fair, if you come from a Javascript background and are used to adding methods to an object by extending the object instance (rather than the `prototype`) I can see where this confusion might come from, but in the CLR (and C++, Java, etc) this is not the case.